# Xamarin forms build error in Android project. Could not load assembly...doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? Pinvoke.dll

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, mono

I have been struggling with this error for weeks and have found similar build errors, but not specific to mono.android

I am using
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.6.1
Version 4.7.02556
NuGet Package Manager   4.6.0

```
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?File name: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke.dll'at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters) at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)   MyProject.Android
```

I am referencing Mono 8 here. I have a bunch of different versions and even tried 4.0.3 and 8.1. Same error.

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAAndroid\v8.0\Mono.Android.dll
```

I have tried updating and removing some nuget packages 
removing mono.android and targeting another version commenting out the
interop references in the app.config like these
Targeting other api levels

```
PInvoke.BCryp,PInvoke.Kernel32,PInvoke.NCrypt,PInvoke.Windows.Core
```

Similar posts above but none for System.Runtime.Interopservices.Pinvoke.dll

[System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly...perhaps doesn't exist in the Mono for Android Profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976760/system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-assembly-perhaps-doesnt-exist)

Please, any advice would suffice

Comment: Hi, could you please provide some steps to reproduce it?